# How to use HTML in LifeRay ShoppingItem description?

Tags: java, html, database, liferay

How can I embed HTML into the ShoppingItem database table "description" field in such a way that it will display on screen?  It used to work in older versions, but in the current version it mangles/safes it to display the HTML tags, rather than passing them through to be processed.

Is there an alternate method to achieve the desired effect?

I'm sure the change to LifeRay was for security purposes, but this table won't be end-user editable in our application and we need to embed links, bold, etc. into the shopping item description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up hacking the appropriate .jsp files with a quick and dirty "replace" to decode the lt and gt characters.  Not pretty, but LifeRay goes well out of it's way to try and keep you from being able to inject HTML of any kind.